# Show a point (circle) on a desired position on SVG

Tags: javascript, svg, position

I have a 12h clock with 47 quarter areas (12h * 4 quarters in one hour). I want to show a point on a defined quarter area of the clock depending on the back-end's response. Assuming the back-end returns me `3`, I have to show a point on the 3rd quarter area.

Here is a fiddle: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/97rbwLd1/3/)

Here my approach:

All quarter areas in the SVG are in the group `<g id="data"></g>`. Each area has an id. After that I want to determine his SVG position and then put a point on that position:

```
function setPointForQuarterCoordonates(id) {
    var quarterObject = document.getElementById(id);
    var coordinates   = quarterObject.getBoundingClientRect();
    var point         = document.createElementNS(NS, 'circle');
    point.setAttributeNS(null, 'cx', coordinates.x);
    point.setAttributeNS(null, 'cy', coordinates.y);
    point.setAttributeNS(null, 'r', 10);

    return point;
}
```

In my exemple, the button "Show Defined Point (3)" simulates this event by adding a point on the 3rd rectangle starting from 12:00. For that I used:

```
var quarterCoordinates = quarterObject.getBoundingClientRect();
```

But the problem is that this gives me the DOM coordinates, not the SVG ones. So if I resize the window and I click on the button 2nd time, the point is added at different position instead at the same.

Do you have any ideas or suggestions how to deal with that?

Comment: Hi Vlad. It's not entirely clear what the question you're asking is. Could you format the question and maybe the title to be a little more clear?

Comment: Hi Samuel Liew and @Ahndwoo is more clear like that? I edited the title and the description and added more code. Can you guys upvote my question please? It'a pitty to have -1 if all is clear :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using `.getBBox();` instead of `getBoundingClientRect();`.

```
function setPointForQuarterCoordonates(id) {

    var quarterObject = document.getElementById(id);
    var coordinates   = quarterObject.getBBox(); // <------------------
    var point         = document.createElementNS(NS, 'circle');
    point.setAttributeNS(null, 'cx', coordinates.x);
    point.setAttributeNS(null, 'cy', coordinates.y);
    point.setAttributeNS(null, 'r', 10);

    return point;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGraphicsElement/getBBox

Comment: Thanks @Ezelev, it worked. Some points are not positioned correctly but it do the job. Do you have any idea why?